# Split lines inside files with fixed width columns

Tags: text-processing, columns, text-formatting

How can I remove dummy information from a file named `results.txt` with lines like this?

Lines inside file are like this:

```
_my0001_split00000000.txt:Total Dynamic Power    =   0.0000 mW        
_my0001_split00000050.txt:Total Dynamic Power    = 117.5261 uW  (100%)
```

... and they should change to a tab-separated format like this:

```
0001    00000000    0.0000  mW  
0001    00000050    117.5261    uW
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a using `sed` instead of `awk`?

```
sed -r 's/^_my([0-9]+)_split([0-9]+)\.txt:[^=]*=\s*([0-9.]+) *(\S+).*/\1\t\2\t\3 \4/' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have GNU `awk`, then you can indeed specify fixed fieldwidths e.g.

```
gawk -vFIELDWIDTHS="3 4 6 8 30 8 1 3" -vOFS="\t" '{print $2,$4,$6,$8}' results.txt
0001    00000000          0.0000        mW
0001    00000050        117.5261        uW
```

However you could also consider a regular expression based solution - for example, in `perl` you could print the first three numeric values plus power units as:

```
perl -lne 'print join "\t", (/\d*\.?\d+|\b.W\b/g)[0..3]' results.txt
0001    00000000        0.0000  mW
0001    00000050        117.5261        uW
```

Answer (score 4):

You *can* do it in `awk`. For example:

```
$ awk -vOFS="\t" '{ 
                    sub(/.txt:.*= */," "); 
                    sub(/^.../,"",$1); 
                    sub(/_split/, "\t",$1); 
                    print $1,$2,$3
                  }' file  
0001    00000000    0.0000  mW
0001    00000050    117.5261    uW
```

It really isn't the best tool for the job though. Awk excels when you want to extract fields unchanged, it can get cumbersome when you need to edit them.

I would instead use something like:

```
$ perl -lne '
    @m=(/\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+).*=\s*([0-9.]+)\s+(\S+).*$/); 
    print join "\t", @m' file 
0001    00000000    0.0000  mW
0001    00000050    117.5261    uW
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/_my//;s/_split/\i/;s/\.txt:Total Dynamic Power *= */\i/' /path/to/input
```

Comment: 6 seconds difference. :D